# Single category and multi categories

Tags: php, laravel

I have articles witch can have one single category that's Main category with category_id.
and additional multi categories with pivot table everything working it's stores but i can't get data on web i'm only getting articles with single category how can i get articles with single and with multi categories in one variable?

article model:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(AllCategory::class, 'category_id', 'id');
}

public function manyCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(AllCategory::class, 'articles_categories', 'article_id', 'category_id')
            ->using(ArticleCategory::class);
}
```

AllCategory model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class, 'category_id', 'id')->orderBy('published_at', 'Desc');
}

public function manyArticles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class, 'articles_categories', 'category_id', 'article_id')
            ->using(ArticleCategory::class);
}
```

and pivot table:

```
class ArticleCategory extends Pivot
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'articles_categories';

    protected $fillable = [
        'article_id', 'category_id'
    ];

    protected $guarded = ['*'];
}
```

and in controller i'm getting like this

```
$offsetPage = ($page - 1);
$perPage = 24;
$category = AllCategory::bySlug($slug);

if (! $category) {
    abort(404);
}

$categoryArticles = $category->articles()
    ->with('manyCategories')
    ->skip($perPage * $offsetPage)
    ->take($perPage)
    ->get();
```

I'm getting single category articles with articles() and i'm trying to get manycategories to ->with but it's only getting me single category articles what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should use only many-to-many relationship in your case. If belonging to a single category is important for your application, you can filter the articals based on the number of their categories after collecting them.

Comment: why not only use the Many To Many relationship and keep a value on the pivot table to declare the category the "main" category?

Comment: This project is already in live and now they want to add multi categories to i can't remove single category and add only multi category because there already is records in base with single category so is there any solution to do both ?

Comment: ideally move to using the pivot table and add those records for the main category to it ... but otherwise you can create an accessor that can add the single category to the collection of categories returned from the many to many relationship as one option

Comment: I do not have much experience to do that. is there any easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You could create an accessor that would add the main category to the Collection of categories that the Article belongs to.

```
public function getCategoriesAttribute()
{
    // adding the main category (if there is one) to the Collection
    return (clone $this->manyCategories)->when(
        this->category,
        fn ($collection, $category) => $collection->prepend($category)
    );
}
```

Controller:

```
$categoryArticles = $category->articles()
    ->with(['category', 'manyCategories'])
    ->skip($perPage * $offsetPage)
    ->take($perPage)
    ->get();
```

View:

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
    @foreach ($article->categories as $category)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Mutators & Casting - Defining an Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-when) - `when`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-prepend) - `prepend`

Comment: Thanks for response. i added getCategoriesAttribute to article model and added ->with in controller but in foreach?  ``` @foreach ($categoryArticles as $article)
    @foreach ($article->categories as $category)
        .
    @endforeach
@endforeach  ``` i didn't get foreach i have in foreach {{$article->title}} and i must get in this single category article title and multi categories article title but if there is 2 foreach how can i get it ?

Comment: Now i have something like this  ```  
        @foreach($categoryArticles as $article)
        <a class="font-medium font-size-14" href="{{$article->category->getUrl()}}">

            <div class="font-size-14 font-size-xs-12">{{$article->category->tr('title')}}</div>
        </a>
        <a class="w-100" href="{{$article->getUrl()}}">

            <div class="w-100 font-size-14 font-size-md-12 pr-xs-15px h-55px h-md-50px h-xs-75px">{{$article->tr('title')}}</div>
        </a>
        @endforeach ```

Comment: i created article and main category was culture and pivot categories was economic and policy now when i go to category/culture where must be only articles with culture category i get 3 same article in culture / economic / policy category